# jQuery callback function after whole scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback

i bound some functions to the 'scroll' event of jquery. With this:

```
$window.bind('scroll', function(){ 
        fn1(...);
        afterScroll(); // function which should fired after whole scrolling.            
})
```

The Problem is, that i want the "afterScroll()" function been fired after all scrolling-iterations. But I think when the user scrolls one time, the event - function will be fired a few times (I tested this with some alerts)
afterScroll() should just add a short animation after the scrolling is definitly finished.

For example: http://activatedrinks.com/

Someone an idea? Thanks

greets,
Yannick

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to call a function after scroll has ended?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5515551/how-to-call-a-function-after-scroll-has-ended) -- please use the search before you ask a new question.

Answer (score 3):

It is hard to say when a user has finished scrolling, and there is no such event.  You have to make the determination as to when a user has "finished" scrolling on your own.  Some users may scroll very slowly, but would still consider it to be a single scroll.  Something like..

```
var scrolltime = false;
$window.scroll(function () {
   fn1(...);
   if (scrolltime) {
      clearTimeout(scrolltime);
   }
   //You consider 500 MS between scrolls to be "done" with scrolling.
   scrolltime = setTimeout(afterScroll, 500);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

you need to [debounce](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/) the callback to `afterScroll`

basically debounce discards all repeated calls to the function except the last one, all you need to do is set a threshold to tell it what 'repeated' is

here is the [source](https://raw.github.com/cowboy/jquery-throttle-debounce/v1.1/jquery.ba-throttle-debounce.js) of the throttle/debounce functions. very nice and useful lib. i usually include it in my projects.

Answer (score 0):

If I got you right, just set the timeout in the end, clear the timeout if the scroll continues.

```
setTimeout(1000, function(){ afterScroll(); });
```