# Detect scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

Can I detect scrolling movement with JS or jQuery?

I'm trying to hide a div only when the user is scrolling, and when he stops scrolling the div shows.

I tried:

```js
window.onscroll(function () {
  $('.footerGeral').hide();
});
```

However it does not work.

Comment: Check this out --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5515551/how-to-call-a-function-after-scroll-has-ended <---

Comment: Surely this is different to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701311/event-when-user-stops-scrolling. @jribeiro wants the object to show once more when the user stops scrolling.

Answer (score 1):

You are almost right, but it is [`.scroll()`](https://api.jquery.com/scroll/):

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
  $('.footerGeral').hide();
});
```

You can do this in pure JavaScript, this way:

```
window.onscroll = function () {
  document.querySelectorAll(".footerGeral")[0].style.display = 'none';
}
```

**Note:** This works only if you have content, that is more than the view. A page with scrollbars.

Comment: how this will handle show div on scroll end ?

Comment: @A.T. Ah... I am not sure. Lemme think of a way.

Comment: Maybe this helps -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701311/event-when-user-stops-scrolling

Comment: @naoxink I just thought of it.

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably want to use the `scroll` event, like so:

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', function(evt) {});
```

Now you can detect how many pixels the user has scrolled with `evt.deltaX` and `evt.deltaY`, or how much has totally been scrolled with `document.body.scrollTop` and `document.body.scrollLeft`.

Answer (score 0):

First: it only works if you actually have overflowing content (with a scrollbar). You will not get the event if you just scroll.

Second, the native syntax is:

```
window.onscroll = function () {
  // Your code
};
```

The jQuery approach is:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
   // Your code
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this combining JQuery `scroll()` with `debounce()` from [jquery.ba-throttle-debounce.js](https://github.com/cowboy/jquery-throttle-debounce) by Ben Alman.

```
$(window).scroll($.debounce( 250, true, function(){
    $('.footerGeral').hide(); //scrolling or scrolling stopped for less than 250 ms
}));
$(window).scroll($.debounce( 250, function(){
    $('.footerGeral').show(); //scrolling stopped for more than 250 ms
}));
```