# jQuery Mobile: scroll event for all platforms

Tags: jquery, scroll

I'm looking for a jQuery-Mobile Event, which is working for all platforms.

```
$(document).bind('scrollstop', function () {});
```

this code works for PCs, but not on my iPhone. (Ridiculously it's working on Chrome for iOS, but it doesn't work on iPhone-Safari ...)

So, my question is: Is there a working implementation of scroll events for iOS **and** Android?

Comment: maybe check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6359214/1476449