# Detecting the end of wheel event JavaScript without jQuery

Tags: javascript, html

I have [my code](http://jsfiddle.net/mQuKj/), and I cannot understand how can I detect end of scroll (when it gets to the bottom of the element).

```
document.getElementById('list').addEventListener('wheel', function () {
    function load() {
       var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();

        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            var p = document.createElement('p');
            p.appendChild(document.createTextNode(i));
            fragment.appendChild(p);
       }
       return fragment;
     }

      // if ( scroll end ) { load new content 
         this.appendChild(load());
      //} 
  }, false);
```

Is there any best practice/algorithm for this task?

Comment: What do you mean by "end of scroll"? AHHH, you mean when it gets to the bottom of the element...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I know when I've stopped scrolling Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4620906/how-do-i-know-when-ive-stopped-scrolling-javascript)

Comment: As you can see I use wheel event not scroll for window

Comment: exchange `scroll` with `wheel`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok,  i get what you wanted to achieve now...

so basically, there are those two properties `.scrollHeight` which is the height of the content in a scrollable element, and `.scrollTop` which returns the current scroll position of the scrollable content.

when you scroll to the end of the scrollable element, its scrolltop + height will be equal to its scrollheight, so your condition should look like this:

```
var myList = document.getElementById('list');
if (myList.scrollTop + myList.offsetHeight == myList.scrollHeight) {
    this.appendChild(load());
}
```

here is your <kbd>**[Fixed Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TheBanana/mQuKj/3/)**</kbd>