# Is there any jQuery library for elements entrance animation while page scroll?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

Any one know a good library for elements entering animation while page scrolling. I have used [animate it](http://jackonthe.net/css3animateit/) library, its awesome, lite and easy to handle but not working with newest version of jQuery(3.x).
Somebody suggest me a good free library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try animate-on-scroll:

https://michalsnik.github.io/aos/

Or if you need a more advanced library with lot more control in your hands, try ScrollMagic:

http://scrollmagic.io/

Comment: I am glad. Welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use [Animate.css](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/) and [Wow.js](https://github.com/matthieua/WOW)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `onscroll` event handler.

```
window.onscroll - function() {
    var el = document.getElementById('animateMe');
    el.addClass('anime');
}
```

where you have the animation included in the `.anime` class.

CSS

```
.anime { 
    animation: yourAnimation 2s ease-out;
}

@keyframes animation { 
    0% {
        background: blue;
    }
    100% { 
        backgroudn: red;
    }
}
```

If you need the animation to stop when not scrolling, see [How do I know when I've stopped scrolling Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4620906/how-do-i-know-when-ive-stopped-scrolling-javascript).