# jQuery event listener when NOT scrolling in the browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I need to target when the browser is not being scrolled:

So far I have this code:

```
var position = jQuery(window).scrollTop(); // how much is scolling
// should start at 0    
jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
    var scroll = jQuery(window).scrollTop();

    if(scroll > position) { // scrolling down
        // do something when scrolling down
    } else if(scroll < position) { // scrolling up
        // do something when scrolling up
    }else { // idle???
        // do something when idle
    }
    position = scroll;    
});
```

Scrolling up and down is working great, but I can't target when there is no scrolling at all. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Just once when user stops scrolling...or repeatedly? What is your use case?

Comment: Not scrolling = default behaviour, you change this behaviour when user scrolls

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I know when I've stopped scrolling?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4620906/how-do-i-know-when-ive-stopped-scrolling)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a variable to track the status of the scrolling, and a timer to determine if the scrolling has been stopped for N seconds.

```
var scroll_active = false;
var scroll_timer = new Date();
```

Start your scroll timer:

```
check_scroll_time();
```

Then, on scroll, re-set the time-stamp in the `scroll_timer` variable:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    scroll_timer = new Date();

    //Your existing code goes here; No-scroll events are handled in check_scroll_time()
    var scroll = jQuery(window).scrollTop();
    if(scroll > position) { // scrolling down
       // do something when scrolling down
    } else if(scroll < position) { // scrolling up
       // do something when scrolling up
    }

});
```

Your scroll-monitoring function just needs to subtract the scroll_timer time from the current time and determine how long since the last scroll event:

```
function check_scroll_time(){
  now = new Date();
  if ((now.getTime() - scroll_timer.getTime())/1000 > 2){
    //No scrolling - do something
  }else{
    //Scrolling is active - do nothing
  }
  setTimeout(function(){ check_scroll_time() },300); //<==== call ad-infinitum
}
```

Example:

```js
var scroll_active = false;
var scroll_timer = new Date();
check_scroll_time();

$(window).scroll(function(){
  scroll_timer = new Date();
});

function check_scroll_time(){
  now = new Date();
  if ((now.getTime() - scroll_timer.getTime())/1000 > 2){
    $('#msg').html('Paused');
  }else{
    $('#msg').html('Scrolling');
  }
  setTimeout(function(){ check_scroll_time() },300);
}
```

```css
body{height:700vh;}
#blurb{position:fixed;top:50px;width:100vw;text-align:center;}
#msg{position:fixed;top:0;right:0;text-align:center;padding:5px;background:wheat;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="msg"></div>
<div id="blurb">Scroll away - watching for a 2-sec pause</div>
```

---

References:

[Javascript Date Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp)