# How to get scroll started event using vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to get an event when a user starts scrolling. There is a way available in JQuery using `scrollstart`.

Is there any way we can achieve the same in vanilla JavaScript?

Comment: Use a timer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4620906/how-do-i-know-when-ive-stopped-scrolling just check if timer === null to know that scroll is starting.

Comment: I read that answer. It won't be accurate, even adjusting the timing may not give a perfect result.

Comment: Why not? if timer is off, the next time the event is triggered is a new scroll start.

Comment: @Triby man try it out at your end first, then post the answer. How would you make the timer null again? using timeout?

Comment: Didn't try it, that's why I'm just commenting. Please elaborate better your question, including what have you tried and you'll get better comments, even a good and reliable answer.

Comment: @Triby, thanks, that works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we tweak [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4620986/2978923) answer a bit, we can achieve both, scroll start and end.

```
var timer = null;
window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
    if(timer === null) {
        console.log('Scroll Started');
    }
    if(timer !== null) {
        clearTimeout(timer);        
    }
    timer = setTimeout(function() {
          console.log('Scroll Stopped');
          timer = null;
    }, 150);
}, false);
```