# How to show the scrollbar only on scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css, custom-scrolling, perfect-scrollbar

I use perfect-scrollbar https://github.com/mdbootstrap/perfect-scrollbar for custom scrollbar. The scrollbar is visible only when you mouse hover the container.

How can I show the bar only on scroll event and hide it on scroll end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using the javascript `onscroll()` function. Try something like this-

```html
<html>

<body onscroll="bodyScroll();">

  <script language="javascript">
    var scrollTimer = -1;

    function bodyScroll() {
      document.body.style.backgroundColor = "white";

      if (scrollTimer != -1)
        clearTimeout(scrollTimer);

      scrollTimer = window.setTimeout("scrollFinished()", 500);
    }

    function scrollFinished() {
      document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    }
  </script>

  <div style="height:2000px;">
    Scroll the page down. The page will turn red when the scrolling has finished.
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

This code is from another stack question- [How do I know when I've stopped scrolling?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4620906/how-do-i-know-when-ive-stopped-scrolling)

Link to `onscroll()` event in js- https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onscroll.asp

Comment: Thank you. But how can I hide scrollbar after scroll event ends?

Comment: I am editing the answer and adding the code.

Comment: You can try any one of the answers from the other question.