# Jump to correct scrollTop with dynamically loading content

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a webpage with multiple categories. Each category has multiple elements as children. On the top, I have a navigation with inline urls. Clicking a url in the navigation will make you jump to the related category.

I am using JQuery animate to scroll smoothly to the category:

```
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $($(this).attr('href')).offset().top +1,
}, 300,'linear')
```

```
<nav>
    <a href="#category-a">Category A</a>
    <a href="#category-b">Category B</a>
    <a href="#category-c">Category C</a>
    <a href="#category-d">Category D</a>
</nav>

<div id="categories">
    <h2 id="category-a">Category A</h2>
    <div class="category">
        <div class="child">...</div>
        <div class="child">...</div>
        <div class="child">...</div>
        <div class="child">...</div>
    </div>
    
    <h2 id="category-b">Category B</h2>
    <div class="category"></div>
    
    <h2 id="category-c">Category C</h2>
    <div class="category"></div>

    <!-- ... -->
</div>
```

The elements of the first category are loaded immediately. The content of the other categories are loaded dynamically using AJAX to save time for the initial page load. When the bottom of the user's window is 100px above a category the category gets loaded so all the content is visible when the category is in the viewport. This all works fine.

Especially when the user scrolls using his mouse. But there is a problem when the user jumps to a category by using the navigation.

When for example `<a href="#category-d">Category D</a>` is clicked in the navigation, the page scrolls to the top position of `#category-d`. But because the user's viewport also went over `#category-b` and `#category-c` those categories also get loaded dynamically resulting in the user landing on the wrong position on the page.

Example of how it goes now:

1. User clicks on `#category-d` in the navigation to go to.
2. The top position of that category is for example 500px. Note that it has this position because `#category-b` and `#category-c` are still empty.
3. Now all the preceding categories also get loaded (because the viewport jumped over all those categories to scroll to the selected category).
4. Those categories get loaded resulting in the new position of `#category-b` being e.g 2000px.
5. The browser stays on the scrollTop of 500px because that was the initial position of `#category-d` when the other categories were still empty.
6. The user sees `#category-b` instead of `#category-d`.

How would I fix this? I tried to use `setTimeout` before jumping to the category, but that is not ideal. I should have a kind of solution that when the user clicks on a category in the navigation, the browser's viewport should focus on that category so that when the top position of that category changes the browser automatically jumps to the new top position until the user scrolls manually.

Comment: How do you load the content of the categories? Can you show use the code for that? If you made a function yourself that triggers the loading, then you could check within it, if the position of the focused category (save what category that is focused at the moment and its position in a variable) has changed through the load and scroll to the new position.

Comment: what @Geshode said. You have to manually intercept the loading of the elements and recalculate the new scrolling position to offset the newly added elements scrollposition change. I wonder how #category-d is loaded to begin with but not the other ones inbetween, that is kinda strange...

Comment: "I wonder how #category-d is loaded to begin with but not the other ones inbetween" - 
@IljaKO Looks to me like the category headers (the h2 elements with the category ids) exist in the HTML from the beginning, so it is possible to jump to category d without having any content loaded.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `wheel` event to handle wheel scrolling specifically, like

```
document.getElementById("myDIV").addEventListener("wheel", myFunction);
```

You can check at your wheel event where the scrolling happened and apply the loading when certain positions are reached. Using this kind of wheel event you can make sure that the wheel scrolling will continue to work properly.

The other thing you want is to avoid loading the content if you "jump" through it, that is, the user is scrolling without a wheel. For this purpose you will need to detect when the scroll has ended.

You can find here ingenious ways to detect when the scrolling has ended: [How do I know when I've stopped scrolling?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4620906/how-do-i-know-when-ive-stopped-scrolling)

Basically, you repeatedly look whether the scroll is still happening and it's advisable in your case to always be aware of the last scroll state. When the scroll ends, you can detect on which content part the user is on and, if its loading was not issued yet, then you can initiate it.